# Find a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{41}$

Tags: polynomials, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

> Find a $7^\text{th}$ degree polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{41}[x]$, so that
> $$
> p(14^i) = i\pmod{41}\ \forall i = 0,1,\ldots,7.
> $$

**Hint:** $3$ is the $8^\text{th}$ primitive root of unity and $3 \cdot 14 = 8 \cdot 36 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{41}$.

**Edit.** I think a good start is to define
$$F=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1
\\
1&14&14^2&14^3&14^4&14^5&14^6&14^7
\\
1&14^2&14^4&14^6&14^8&14^{10}&14^{12}&14^{14}\\
1&14^3&14^6&14^9&14^{12}&14^{15}&14^{18}&14^{21}\\
1&14^4&14^8&14^{12}&14^{16}&14^{20}&14^{24}&14^{28}\\
1&14^5&14^{10}&14^{15}&14^{20}&14^{25}&14^{30}&14^{35}\\
1&14^6&14^{12}&14^{18}&14^{24}&14^{30}&14^{36}&14^{42}\\
1&14^7&14^{14}&14^{21}&14^{28}&14^{35}&14^{42}&14^{49}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
and then solve $$FP=B,$$ where
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}p_0&p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4&p_5&p_6&p_7\end{pmatrix}^t$$
and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\end{pmatrix}^t.$$
How to solve $FP=B$?

How does one solve such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall write $w$ for $14$.  Note that $w^8=1$.  For $k=0,1,2,\ldots,8$, consider the polynomial
$$f_k(x):=\frac{w^k}{8}\left(\frac{x^8-1}{x-w^k}\right)=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{\left(w^{-k}x\right)^8-1}{w^{-k}x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{8}\left(\sum_{r=0}^7\,w^{-kr}x^r\right)\,.$$
Furthermore, for $l=0,1,2,\ldots,8$ with $l \neq k$, $f_k\left(w^l\right)=0$, whereas $f_k\left(w^k\right)=1$.  The unique polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{41}[x]$ satisfying the condition is $p(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^7\,k\,f_k(x)$.  That is, $$p(x)=\frac{1}{8}\,\sum_{k=0}^7\,k\,\sum_{r=0}^7\,w^{-kr}x^r=\frac{1}{8}\,\sum_{r=0}^7\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^7\,k\,w^{-kr}\right)\,x^r\,.$$

Now, consider $g(x)=\dfrac{x^8-1}{x-1}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^7\,x^r$.  Then, $$\sum_{k=0}^7\,k\,x^k=x\,g'(x)=\frac{8x^8}{x-1}-\frac{x\left(x^8-1\right)}{(x-1)^2}\,.$$  Thus, $$\sum_{k=0}^7\,k\,w^{-kr}=w^{-r}\,g'\left(w^{-r}\right)=\frac{8}{w^{-r}-1}$$ for $r=1,2,\ldots,7$.  Consequently, $$p(x)=24+\sum_{r=1}^7\,\frac{1}{w^{-r}-1}\,x^r=24+\sum_{r=1}^7\,\frac{1}{3^r-1}\,x^r\,,$$
as $w^{-1}=14^{-1}=3$.  That is, $$p(x)=24+21x+36x^2+30x^3+20x^4+10x^5+4x^6+19x^7\,.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'am looking for a solution that uses FFT algorithm. I will try my luck at computer science stackexchange.

Comment: If that is what you wanted, then let $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^7\,p_kx^k$ for some $p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_7\in\mathbb{F}_{41}$.  Then, consider the FFT matrix $\mathbf{F}:=\left[w^{ij}\right]_{i,j\in[7]}$, where $[7]:=\{0,1,2,\ldots,7\}$, and vectors $\mathbf{p}:=\left(p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_7\right)$ and $\mathbf{q}:=\left(0,1,2,\ldots,7\right)$.  The inverse is $\mathbf{F}^{-1}=\frac{1}{8}\left[w^{-ij}\right]_{i,j\in[7]}$.  Hence, the condition on $p(x)$ is the same as saying $\mathbf{Fp}=\mathbf{q}$, which then implies $\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{F}^{-1}\mathbf{q}$, and the rest is only computation.

Comment: That is closer to what I was looking for, thank you.